# I'M having hard time while integrating live ID with my MVC Website

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, liveid

I started to search 3 days ago and I already reached a good point by authenticating the user's and getting back the login session which contains the following data :

```
access_token: "xxxx"
authentication_token: "xxxx"
expires: "1339934686"
expires_in: 3600
```

I want to get the user data and, if you have a previous knowledge, you will know that I need to Decode the  `authentication_token` value to get a JSON object containing some properties including the UserID to get the user data.

When I try to include the `JsonWebToken.cs` class, which was supplied by Microsoft example, in my MVC site it couldn't
resolve some references such as :

```
System.Runtime.Serialization.Json;
DataContractJsonSerializer;
```

When i searched i found that i must add reference to

```
System.Runtime.Serialization.Json,
System.ServiceModel,
System.ServiceModel.Web.
```

When I did that no thing happened new.

Finally, I apologize for the long post, but my intent was to explain the problem and the steps I gone through.

I hope any body could give me a simple MVC example URL or help me with the token decoding by any why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this will not cover your question fully, but here is a nice post where ASP.NET MVC app uses LiveID but doesn't use an ASP.NET Membership provider:

http://blog.smarx.com/posts/actually-i-m-a-cia-agent

1) Reference for documentation is here: [Windows Live ID Web Authentication SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb676633.aspx)

2) and [Live Connect Developer Center](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/live//default.aspx)